# Enumerating all bases of vector space of rank n over the finite field $\{0,1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

I need to create all bases of a vector space of rank $n$, as efficiently as possible (not going over all $n\text{ x }n$ matrices and deciding if they're a basis). My field is $\{0,1\}$, meaning for $n$, I have $2^{n^2}$ matrices, so if i need to test each matrix to see if it's a basis it won't work for $n>10$..

Any suggestions?

Thx in advance

eiran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{F}_2)$ has **a lot** of elements, namely
$$ (2^n-1)\cdot(2^n-2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(2^n-2^{n-1})=2^{n^2}\prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^j}\right) $$
that is just a constant factor away from $2^{n^2}$, since:
$$ \prod_{j=1}^{+\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^j}\right)=0.288788\ldots$$

Not even the most clever method can decrease the complexity of your problem.

Comment: first, i'd like to thank you for your time:). 
now, let's say i don't need all different orderings of a certain basis (the first vector could be the third, it's all the same to me) and A and At (transpose) are the same to me. that bring us down a notch on that number.. like dividing by 2*n! right?

Comment: @eiran: yes, you are right, but $0.144\frac{2^{n^2}}{n!}$ is still huge for moderately large $n$.